# Film involving a white-haired (maybe old) man with spider legs

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this one episode film when I was a child around 1996 or so.  It was not a series film. It was a fantasy/sci-fi  film.  I do remember one battle scene where  there was a white-haired (maybe old) man who is human from the waist up and has spider-feet below that.
Knowing the name of that film would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Noted. I will do that when someone identifies.

Comment: Was this an actual movie (length >= ~90min) or a standalone TV episode (length 30min or 60min)?  Live-action or animated?

Comment: @DavidW It was not an animated  but a live action movie  of approximately 90 min. It was one standalone episode.

Comment: Please describe that battle a bit. Were they using magic or some weapons?

Comment: Could take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi I just remember there was a fight. With who ?  a woman ? Something like that but there was a meeting between a woman I don’t remember the aspect and the old man that is half human half spider.  The spider-man (I will call him so) was walking in a path and a building, I would go for a skyscraper, was on his left but I don’t remember thing on the right side and he meets the one he will fight against.

Comment: I have just remembered this: the Spider-Man lost the battle against the other character (I really think it was a woman) who killed him by decapitation. Not sure of the decapitation but the winner had a long sword during the battle. 
I will continue adding if I recall other details.

Comment: When you say spider legs, is that shape or number? Did he only have 2 legs? Also, could you remember ethnicity? Caucasian? Asian? What language did you see it in?

Comment: @ArlettaS He had six legs in shape and numbers as a spider. The ethnicity I do remember some description but don’t know how to call it as I am not so familiar with Europe/American continents ethnicity difference making. Allow me to take Dolph Lundgren skin type,face,and hair but older and less robust. His skin tone is darker than albino’s with eyes different.  I don’t know how to better say it. Let me pick another actor to explain : Daniel Craig (James Bond) face and eyes look a bit like the old spider-man’s . I hope this helps because I don’t know the right name.

Comment: @ArlettaS The film was in French because of where I come from in Africa but I  believe it has been a translated version for french speakers like us.

Comment: It's not [Lost in Space](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120738/) (1996) is it? Not in black and white, but mostly greyish metal backgrounds in many scenes. I think the villain ends up merging with spider alien robots somehow.

Comment: @bob1 Thanks for the comment. I checked scènes of the movie quoted, it is not that one.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the movie you are looking for is ***[Earth vs. the Spider](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0282178/)*** (2001).

> A shy, obsessive comic book fan gets injected with an experimental serum of a lab that is studying how to give humans the abilities of spiders. At first he develops minor abilities such as increased strength, which allows him to fight local criminals and bullies, thus living out his dream of being a superhero, and impressing his attractive next-door neighbor. Things start to get more odd when he is able to shoot webs out of his abdomen. Then he loses control over the force with which he applies his increasingly deadly abilities, as well as his judgment to discern between criminals and jokesters. His dream becomes a nightmare when he starts growing large spider body parts, he's in constant pain, and he develops a nearly insatiable hunger. A detective with a traumatized wife begins investigating when bodies covered in cobwebs and spider venom start piling up.